# latest jwt token is not updated in vue

Tags: vue.js, jwt

I have an issue that once a user sign in the user is not updated with latest data and I don't see it in the UI.

User is part of the last returned token object and I can see in the console that vue loads the user w/ it's previous state, not loading it again with the last received token after jwt was renewed and set as persistent.

I think I need to create a computed on the function that returns the token, or the token property that changes, I`m not sure...

following code:

`root-component.vue`

```
<template>
  <app v-bind:tokenInstance="tokenInstance" v-bind:saveUserLocales="saveUserLocales"></app>
</template>

<script>
const { getTokenInstance, getTokenInstanceFromStorage, fetchProtectedApi } = require('../auth/jwt.js');
const { onAkuoJwtChanged } = require('../jwt-akuo-token-listener.js');
const { sendToAllTabs } = require('../cross-environment-code/messaging');

const storedTokenInstance = getTokenInstanceFromStorage();

const rootComponent = {
  components: {
    'app': require('./app.vue')
  },
  data() {
    return {
      tokenInstance: storedTokenInstance
    };
  },
  created() {
    onAkuoJwtChanged(this.setTokenInstance);
    console.log('creation of function onAkuoJwtChanged with ');
  },
  methods: {
    setTokenInstance(jwt) {
      console.log('setTokenInstance:', jwt)
      this.tokenInstance = getTokenInstance(jwt);
    },
    // this could probably be ubstracted to a more generic `saveUser`. Maybe we will save user elsewhere too and we do not want to deal with seting token there as well
    saveUserLocales(userId, locales) {
      return fetchProtectedApi(`users/${userId}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: { locales }
      }).then(
        ({ token }) => {
          this.setTokenInstance(token); // this could be removed if sending singedIn would trigger a local storage set and this in turn would trigger onAkuoJwtChanged that calls thissetTokenInstance
          // here -> engine.content -> background page (where we store the token)
          sendToAllTabs({
            fn: 'signedIn',
            message: token
          }); // this is fine since both options page and background page share the same localStorage! according to this stackoverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8790423
        },
        (error) => {
          // TODO notify user that it failed
          console.error(error);
        }
      );
    }
  }
};
```

```
app.vue
```

```
<template>
  <div>
    <no-token v-if="displaySignIn" v-bind:tokenInstance="tokenInstance"></no-token>
    <with-chosen-locales v-else v-bind:userLocales="user.locales" v-bind:saveUserLocales="saveUserLocales" v-bind:userId="userId"></with-chosen-locales>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const { getUserIntance } = require('../models/user');
module.exports = {
  components: {
    'no-token': require('./no-token.vue'),
    'no-locales': require('./no-locales.vue'),
    'with-chosen-locales': require('./with-chosen-locales.vue')
  },
  props: ['tokenInstance', 'saveUserLocales'],
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  computed: {
    displaySignIn() {
      console.log('displaySignIn: ', (!this.tokenInstance || this.tokenInstance.isExpired()));
      return !this.tokenInstance || this.tokenInstance.isExpired();
    },
    hasNotChosenLocales() {
      console.log('hasNotChosenLocales: ', (this.userInstance && !this.userInstance.hasChosenLocales()))
      return this.userInstance && !this.userInstance.hasChosenLocales();
    },
    hasNotDetectedLocales() {
      console.log('hasNotDetectedLocales: ', (this.userInstance && !this.userInstance.detectedLocales()))
      return this.userInstance && !this.userInstance.detectedLocales();
    },
    user() {
      console.log('user: ', this.tokenInstance.getUser())
      return this.tokenInstance.getUser();
    },
    userInstance() {
      console.log('userInstance: ', this.user && getUserIntance(this.user))
      return this.user && getUserIntance(this.user);
    },
    userId() {
      console.log('userId: ', (this.userInstance && this.userInstance.getJson()._id))
      return this.userInstance && this.userInstance.getJson()._id;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

with-chosen-locales.vue

```
<template>
<div v-if="isEditMode === false">
    <div>chosen locales</div>
    <template v-for="localeObj in chosenLocales">
      <div>{{localeObj.locale}}</div>
    </template>
    <button v-on:click="switchToEditMode">Edit</button>
</div>
<div v-else>
    <div>Edit locales</div>
    <template v-for="localeObj in availableLocales">
      <input type="checkbox" id="localeObj.locale" v-bind:checked="localeObj.chosen" v-on:click="localeObj.chosen = !localeObj.chosen">
      <label for="localeObj.locale">{{localeObj.locale}}</label>
    </template>
    <button v-on:click="save">Save</button>
</div>
</template>
<script>
const { fetchProtected } = require('../auth/jwt.js');
function cloneLocales(locales) {
  return locales.map(x => Object.assign({}, x));
}
module.exports = {
  props: ['userLocales', 'saveUserLocales', 'userId'],
  data() {
    return { 
      componentLocales: cloneLocales(this.userLocales),
      availableLocales: [],
      editMode: false };
  },
  computed: {
    chosenLocales() {
      return this.componentLocales.filter(x => x.chosen);
    },
    isEditMode()
    {
      console.log('this.userLocales:', this.userLocales);
      return this.editMode;
    }
  },
    methods: {
    switchToEditMode() {
      return fetchProtected(`data/list.json`, {
        method: 'GET'
      }).then(
        (v) => {
          this.availableLocales = v.map(l => {
            return {
              locale:l,
              chosen: this.chosenLocales.filter(x => x.locale === l).length > 0
            };});
          this.editMode = true;
        },
        (error) => {
          // TODO notify user that it failed
          console.error(error);
        }
      );
     },

    save() {
      this.saveUserLocales(this.userId, this.availableLocales.filter(x => x.chosen));
      this.componentLocales = this.availableLocales;
      this.editMode = false;
    },
}};
</script>
```

Your kind assistance,
Assaf

Answer (score 0):

You clearly have to use Vuex for this task.

You are sending your token from root to child components - are you going to add this property to **every** component that needs it? That's why Vuex is needed. It synchronises the data across whole application.

Move all your token receiving logic to Vuex module, like this:

1. Create token in Vuex state with initial value fetched from storage
2. Create mutation that will set token to storage and set token in state
3. Create action that will call API and pass token to mutation
4. Create getter to use this token from Vuex

This is also explained here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/handling-authentication-in-vue-using-vuex

Comment: well, I don't HAVE to, vuex is just for convenience and write less code, I need to understand what's going on before I add more stuff to the current code.

besides, the vue code of the app is quite small.

+ Also, I realize the problem is not that the token not updated in Vue, but the user object, specific the userLocales object is not updated to the latest user.locales.
For some reason the user() (inside app.vue) runs only once, I can't figure out why...

once the user will be updated, my problem will be resolved.